# Reset GitHub login when using composer install

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I just used composer to install some dependencies for a project. In this project we are using the cartalyst/sentry-social package. To get this I have to use a special GitHub account - but I didn't know that wehen I was using the command about an hour age :/

So now I have entered the wrong GitHub Login Credentials and somehow this gets saved and I didn't figured out how to reset them, so composer/git would ask me again for the login credentials.

So how do I reset this login credentials?

Answer (score 7):

Muahaha!

Already found that out :)

So if you tried it with the wrong login like me, you can go to ~/.config/composer/auth.json and remove the entry with its token from the file.

```
{       
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "xxxxxxyourtokenxxxxx"
    }
}
```

to

```
{   
}
```

and then run

```
composer clearcache
```

Hope that helps I just spent one and a half hour trying to get there ...

Comment: Where this file auth.json located in windows machine?

Comment: this `~/.composer/auth.json` means that the file is located under `/home/<username>/.composer/auth.json` in a linux/unix system. But if you asking something like this, you probably are from a windows environment, where you should look into the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/). Hope that helps :)

Comment: Sometimes, an additional `composer clearcache` run may be helpful after that